# Send request on webservice from URL

Tags: python, web-services, post, get, spyne

I have SOAP webservice written in python with Spyne module..

This is it:

```
class Function(spyne.Service):
    __service_url_path__ = '/soap';
    __in_protocol__ = Soap11(validator='lxml');
    __out_protocol__ = Soap11();

    @spyne.srpc(Unicode, _returns=Iterable(Unicode))
    def Function(A):
        #some code

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host = '127.0.0.1');
```

And I need to send request on that server from URL.
It should look like this:

```
IP:port/soap/function?A=1
```

But when I try it, this appears:

```
You must issue a POST request with the Content-Type header properly set
```

But I don´t know what it is.. How it should be properly?
Can someone help with it?

Should I just change that URL, or server code too?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So,
now, I have it.

**This is correct way:**

```
class Function(spyne.Service):
    __service_url_path__ = '/soap';
    __in_protocol__ = HttpRpc(validator='soft'); #this is it 
    __out_protocol__ = Soap11();
```

Now, I can **call web service from URL** like this:

```
IP:port/soap/function?A=1
```

So, this is it..
I hope that it will help someone sometimes :)